# scrollHeight not resetting after programmatically changing content

Tags: javascript, resize, user-input

I am trying to learn a few things without jQuery. Here is one of the challenges I'm facing.

I have a fixed **contenteditable** div that when adding text to the div, if the `scrollHeight` exceeds the `clientHeight` I shrink the font until content fits the div.

Occasionally I "rebuild" the text which replaces the `innerHTML` programmatically. Or the user can delete text which *should* reduce the `scrollHeight`, but in both cases, the `scrollHeight` remains the maximum value. I need some way to increase the font size to "fit" the div again. (that ideally isn't super expensive)

Example:

My `clientHeight` = 142, and the `scrollHeight` = 158. A loop reduces the font size, until `scrollHeight` is 142.
Then, the user deletes a line of text, but the `scrollHeight` is still 142, no change.

code to reduce/increase height:

```
    var textBox = document.getElementById('text');
    var current, min = 6, max = 14;
    current = textBox.style.fontSize.substr(0, textBox.style.fontSize.length - 2);
    current = parseInt(current);
    if (textBox.clientHeight < textBox.scrollHeight) {
        while (textBox.clientHeight < textBox.scrollHeight) {
            current--;
            if (current < min) break;
            textBox.style.fontSize = '' + current + 'pt';
        }
    } else if (textBox.clientHeight > textBox.scrollHeight) {
        while (textBox.clientHeight > textBox.scrollHeight) {
            current++;
            if (current > max) break;
            textBox.style.fontSize = '' + current + 'pt';
        }
    }
```

html (incase it matters):

```
<div id="text" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

css (incase it matters):

```
#text {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    top: 180px;
    left: 31px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 132px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-family: 'mplantin';
    font-size: 14pt;
    font-weight: 200;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was on the same boat, but with an `iframe`; I'm not sure if my solution suits your chat window because its for page transitioning, but after some testing this is my hack. `"content"` is the id of an `iframe` and this is executed inside a javascript function that is called when the page change is needed:

```
var c=document.getElementById("content");
c.width=0;
c.height=0;
c.src="page.html";
```

the `src' assignment method expands the values set to 0 right after, achieving the desired result; there may be a way for you to constantly re-size a text area like that; however, I had visual issues with you; I ended up using timers so that the change would take place while the transition between pages was transparent.

Answer (score 3):

This seemed to fix my issue:

```
element.style.height = "auto";
```

Answer (score 1):

both answers from @nixahn and @jeff are working for me (chrome,ff)

```
iframe.style.height ="0"; // or "auto"
iframe.contentWindow.document.open();
iframe.contentWindow.document.write('<style>'+css+'</style>');
iframe.contentWindow.document.write(html);
iframe.contentWindow.document.close();
```

Comment: auto does not work if I have initially lets say 3 rows. But 0 does the trick!

Answer (score 0):

I have used a div with a fixed height, and the problem with auto is that it resizes the element, I fixed that with the following code after my inner HTML was set:

`element.style.height = "auto";
 element.style.height = "400px";`

now scrollHeight is resetted correctly and gives the real height of the inner HTML

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue -- A content editable div whose `scrollHeight` wouldn't shrink when lines were removed.

The accepted answer didn't fix the problem for me, however, removing the div's parent's `display: flex;` did.